# js not working with onsubmit

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

Seen a lot of posts about this subject but nothing seems to work for me:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openprompt(){
            $.prompt("Hello World!");   
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="javascript:openprompt()">Test Impromptu States Survey</a>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    some code.....
        <div id="formWrapper">
                <form action="create.php" method="post" onsubmit="return openprompt();">
```

If I click on the link the js script runs fine and opens the prompt window, however when I click the submit button that's attached to the form the script doesn't run. I checked the database and see that the php script is running fine. Can anyone please explain why the js script is not running and a way to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Cause it actually submits your form (and loads `create.php`)

Comment: I just used generic code: <div id="submitButton">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" style="margin: auto"/>

Answer (score 1):

That's because the submit will trigger a redirect to the form's action. you must disable this:

```
<form action="create.php" method="post" onsubmit="openprompt(); return false;">
```

A better way to do this, would be to catch the event in javascript (for instance with jQuery):

form tag:

```
<form action="create.php" method="post" id="my-form">
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {    
    $('#my-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the actual submit

        openprompt();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe I want to submit the form and run the php script so the database can be updated, but when I do I also want to run the js script. Will the above recommendation stop the php script from running?

Comment: stopping the submit will not run the php code, what do you want the js code to do right before a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `openprompt` is run, but your server sends a new page, and you can't see the prompt "window".

This happens because `$.prompt()` creates/shows a `div` or some other element, which emulates modal dialog. However, JS can't create real modals, hence the prompt is not really blocking the script, and the execution continues to the end of `openprompt`. Because `false` is not returned, submit button will do its work and submits the form.

To fix this you need to use `input type="button"` instead of submit button, and add `onclick` to that button to show the prompt. Then submit the form from `$.prompt`'s callback function when needed.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
<form action="create.php" method="post" onsubmit="openprompt">
```

Comment: this will still just redirect to the form's action